# Strange characters in c

Tags: c

This is my source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    int broj_znakova,i=0;
    char niz1[81],niz2[81];

    printf("Enter something, for end Ctrl/c \n\n");
    while(fgets(niz1,81,stdin)!=NULL)
    {
        continue;
    }
    printf("You just enter: %s \n",niz1);
    printf("This string is long %d\n",(strlen(niz1)-1));
    strcpy(niz1,niz2);
    printf("niz2 is %s\n",niz2);
    if(strcmp(niz1,niz2)==0)
    {
        printf("niz1 and niz2 is same\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("niz1 != niz2\n");
    }
    while(niz1[i]!='\n')
    {
        if(niz1[i]==' ')
        {
            broj_znakova ++;
            i=i+1;
        }
    }
    printf("Spaces in string = %d\n",broj_znakova);
}
```

When i press Ctrl/c i got a bunch of strange characters, can someone help???
I google something about flushing but i'm new :)

Comment: Ctrl+C usually terminates your process; you should be pressing Ctrl+D to close stdin.

Comment: i try Ctrl+d and nothing also try Ctrl+x nothin, but Crtl+c work for me but my niz1 is too many stange characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of `niz2` is not initialized.  It will result in undefined behavior.  Perhaps you meant to copy `niz1` to `niz2`.  If so, then you need to reverse the parameters in the `strcpy` call.  With `strcpy`, the first parameter is the target.

Note too that the variable `broj_znakova` is never initialized.

Comment: Ok i replace this in strcpy, but i need to know why my niz1 store some strange characters after Ctrl+c

Comment: @StefanCvetkovic:  I am not able to reproduce the printing of the strange characters.  And (as dasblinkenlight stated in a comment), the ctrl+c sequence kills the process, so nothing is printed if I press that key combination.

Answer (score 1):

C does not "zero out" information in memory (in general) so when it allocates variables, you get whatever is there in memory at the time (whether it is logically readable as words or not), if you are printing something without the system knowing this is a string then it will keep printing until it encounters a NULL terminating character, if there is none, it tries to print whatever is in memory and this produces the weird characters.

Comment: Is it same while(fgets(niz1,81,stdin)!=NULL) and while(fgets(niz1,81,stdin)!=EOF) ???

Comment: Very similar. NULL is for strings and other streams while EOF is for end of file so that assumes you're using a file to get your information. But in effect they are the same but must be used for different situations.

Answer (score 0):

On this line

```
strcpy(niz1,niz2);
```

I believe your parameters are reverse, it should be strcpy(niz2, niz1);   The strange characters you are seeing is because niz2[81] has memory allocated, but it's not "filled in".  So you get whatever 'magical' data that allocation may contain.  That is, until you put something in it, or do memset, etc.